# Tic Tac Toe displaying a grid

Tags: python

I am currently making a tic tac toe game in Python, and I want to allow the user to see the board every time a move is made. The user is playing against the computer (I have coded it so that the computer analyzes the board and makes a move) and then each player switches off until a player wins, ties, or loses. What I want to print is something like this:

```
moveList=[['X','-','-'],['O','X','-'],['X','O','-']])

<------->
< x - - > #element 1 of the list, so the first sublist
< o x - > #element 2 of the list, so the second sublist
< x o - > #element 3 of the list, so the third sublist
<------->
```

Where I establish a header and footer (I know how to do this), and use a 2D list that I store the moves in to display them each time a new move is made. this would be accomplished by using two for loops and newlines, but I am unsure of how to do this. Any tips would be appreciated! - Note: I only need some assistance on printing the rows of the 2D list, everything else works fine.

EDIT:

I have tried a double for loop:

```
for a in range(len(moveList)):
     for b in range(len(moveList[a])):
          print moveList[a][b],
```

But have had no success, since I need it to only print three elements at a time.

Comment: I've tried the for loop thing, where I did

Comment: What Python do you use? Beware: `print` versus `print()`

Comment: if you have specific questions about your code, add your code to the question and ask your questions. Otherwise we cannot help you.

Answer (score 2):

Since `moveList` is an iterable, it is better style to iterate over it directly, rather than iterating over a range which you then use to index the list.

```
print '<------->'
for row in moveList:
  print '< ' + ' '.join(row) + ' >'
print '<------->'
```

A clever alternative to `str.join` might be to use list unpacking with the `*` symbol, something like

```
for row in moveList:
  print '< {} {} {} >'.format(*row)
```

Comment: how would I do the same thing if the player decided to play tic tac toe on a custom board, i.e. where the dimensions could be something like 5x4 and not 3x3? and thank you, this helped!

Comment: It should still work as is because the `.join` method doesn't care how many things are in the row, You would just need to adjust the length of the top and bottom boundaries.

Comment: When I try it with different moveList lengths, it only prints the first three elements, skips the forth, and then continues from there, and so on. And could you please elaborate on the boundaries concept? Thanks

Comment: Are you using the first method with `' '.join`, it should generalise fine.  Forget that thing with `*row`

Comment: I tried using the first method, and I keep getting a "sequence item 0: expected string, int found" error. Should I format the moveList to all strings first?

Comment: Yes.  Note the code in your question already has all strings...

Comment: Thank you wim, it all worked out!